# Determining when $\phi(m) + \phi(n) = \phi(mn)$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, totient-function

I am working on a take home exam so I am allowed hints but no full solutions (Attaching link to my Exam).

The question I am stuck on is asking to determine for which $m, n$ does $\phi(m) + \phi(n) = \phi(mn)$. I have a solution but wanted to check if it has any holes.

Suppose $m, n$ are coprime. Then, $\phi(mn) = \phi(m)\phi(n)$ so that $\phi(m) + \phi(n) = \phi(m)\phi(n)$. This implies that $\phi(m) (\phi(n) - 1) = \phi(n)$. The only way this is possible is if $\phi(m) = \phi(n) = 2$. Since $\phi(m) = 2$ implies $m,n = 3,4,$ or $6$ and $m, n$ are coprime, $(m,n) = (3,4)$ or $(4,3)$.

For the case when $m, n$ are not coprime, we know that $\phi(mn) > \phi(m)\phi(n)$ so we want $\phi(m) + \phi(n) \ge \phi(m)\phi(n)$. Letting $\phi(m) = a$ and $\phi(n) = b$, we want $a + b \ge ab$. Now, dividing by $ab$ gives us $\frac{1}{b} + \frac{1}{a} \ge 1$. This only holds when one of $a, b$ = 1 or both $a,b = 2$.

We first work with the case where $a,b$ = 2. Then, from above, we have to check $(m,n) = (3,6), (6,3), (4,6)$ and $(6,4)$. However, a quick check shows us that $\phi(m) + \phi(n) = 4 < \phi(18), \phi(24) = 6, 8$. For the other case, due to its symmetric nature, we can assume $a = 1$ or, in other words, $m$ = 2. So, it suffices to find $n$ such that $\phi(n) + 1 = \phi(2n)$, where $2 \mid n$ as well ($m, n$ not coprime).

Letting $n = 2 *\prod_{i=1}^{k} p_i^{a_i}$, where $p_i$ are distinct odd primes we get $\phi(2n) = 2n * \frac{1}{2} * \prod_{i=1}^{k} (\frac{p_i-1}{p_i}) = n * \prod_{i=1}^{k} (\frac{p_i-1}{p_i})= 2 * \frac{n}{2} * \prod_{i=1}^{k} (\frac{p_i-1}{p_i}) = 2\phi(n)$. So, $\phi(n) + 1 = \phi(2n) = 2\phi(n) \implies \phi(n) = 1 \implies n = 2$. Hence, when $m, n$ are not coprime, $m, n = (2,2)$.

Comment: If $p$ is a prime then $\phi(p)=p-1$, which is not equal to $2$ unless $p=3$.

Comment: Thank you for catching my mistake.

Comment: Write down values for $\varphi$ and see if you can spot a pattern, maybe even a formula, which might help I think

Comment: The coprime case can also be solved as follows : with $x=\phi(m)$ and $y=\phi(n)$ we get $x+y=xy$, which is equivalent to $xy-x-y+1=1$, so $(x-1)(y-1)=1$ , so $x=y=2$ implying $x,y=3,4\ or\ 6$. So the only coprime pairs are $(3/4)$ and $(4/3)$. Seems that $x=y=2$ is the only solution with $x,y$ not coprime, but I have no proof yet.

Comment: @Peter I think I have the proof

Comment: @YunusSyed Now, I also have it. I asked a question, in which it was shown that we have $$\phi(mn)>\phi(m)\cdot \phi(n)$$ if $m$ and $n$ are not coprime. With $x=\phi(m)$ and $y=\phi(n)$ , we get $x+y>xy$, which leads to $x=1$ or $y=1$. WLOG, we have $x=1$, so $m=2$ and the equation becomes $1+\phi(n)=\phi(2n)$ and because of $\phi(2n)=2\phi(n)$ for even $n$ (And $n$ must be even because it is not coprime to $2$) we get $1+y=2y$, so we get $y=1$ and $n=2$

Comment: Yes sir! Good work